# Looping through extended methods: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, class, methods, foreach, extends

I'm trying to loop through different options from extended classes in my parent class, but I keep getting this error with my foreach statement:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Not sure why this is happening, any idea what I'm missing? Not sure why `$this->options()` isn't recognized as an array... I've gotten a similar thing to work before, but I think something is just shooting right over my head here:

```
class parent_class {
    public function my_method() {
        $options = $this->options();
        foreach($options as $option) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public function options() {
    }
}

class child_one extends parent_class {
    public function options() {
        $options['name_one'] = array(
            'type' => 'type_one',
            'id' => 'id_one',
            'name' => 'name_one'
        );
        return $options;
    }
}

class child_two extends parent_class {
    public function options() {
        $options['name_two'] = array(
            'type' => 'type_two',
            'id' => 'id_two',
            'name' => 'name_two'
        );
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try var_dump() variable to see if it is considered as an array.

Comment: Hey @Dukeling, this is PHP.

Comment: @fedorqui, they do come out as arrays, but they're all separate. I'm thinking I may need to merge all the different instances of $options into one array maybe?

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

is telling you that `foreach` expects an array to be provided to is as first argument.
You provide to it `$options = $this->options()` and since the `options()` method is empty, it's return value is `NULL` therefore setting `$options = NULL`.

To avoid it you could:

```
$options = $this->options();
if (is_array($options))
    foreach($options as $option) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That does get rid of the error, but I do need that `foreach` to loop through each case of `$this->options()` from the extended classes, and it still doesn't do that for a reason I can't figure out. :/

Comment: @AlexMangini Your `$this->options()` is not returning anything. You have defined `options` as an empty method (`public function options() {}`).

Comment: Yes, I defined it so the extended classes could overwrite  that empty method. Otherwise, I'd get the error that $this->options() is an undefined method.

Comment: @AlexMangini, could you provide the code in which you are getting the error?